# Word 2010 mail merge: state a repeated field only once when populating results

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, mail-merge

I have this Excel file:

[exel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXAQd.jpg)

As you can see it's simple, only three columns: city, customer and paid.

I need to create a Word file from this Excel using mail merge in the format I show in the following image: the city is stated only once.

[word file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diCW7.jpg)

I know how to order by city name using mail merge, but I don't know how to go on populating the rest of the format.

Can you please tell me how to do so?

Many thanks

Comment: "how to go on populating the rest of the format." <-- what is the rest of the format? postcode/road name? Or.. your are referring to the blank cells?

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Here it is just in case it is needed:

```
IF {MERGEFIELD} = 1
```

Thanks